# Seeking explanation - small change in code makes VBA excel crash

Tags: excel, vba

Difficult to explain in just title. I'm trying to understand why small change in code makes excel crash

The idea is, finds specific position of cell with value "test", checks if row above is empty, deletes it if it is empty. If not empty, then tests row above it and so on.

Initial working code

```
Sub testcode()

**Dim test As Boolean**
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRange As Range
Dim Row1 As Integer
Dim rshift As Integer

Range("E508").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "test"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
Loop

Row1 = 0
Row1 = ActiveCell.Row

rshift = 0
Do While Row1 > 626
    Set rRange = Range("A" & (Row1 - 1 - rshift) & ":" & "AD" & (Row1 - 1 - rshift))
    **test = 0**
    For Each rCell In rRange
        If Not IsEmpty(rCell.Value) Then
            rshift = rshift + 1
            **test = 1**
            Exit For
        End If
    Next rCell
    **If test = 0 Then**
        Rows((Row1 - 1 - rshift)).EntireRow.Delete
        Row1 = Row1 - 1
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Vs. code that causes Excel to crash. I only changed initial `test` variable value, and conditions in `if then` tests

```
Sub testcode()

**Dim test As Boolean**
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRange As Range
Dim Row1 As Integer
Dim rshift As Integer

Range("E508").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "test"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
Loop

Row1 = 0
Row1 = ActiveCell.Row

rshift = 0
Do While Row1 > 626
    Set rRange = Range("A" & (Row1 - 1 - rshift) & ":" & "AD" & (Row1 - 1 - rshift))
    **test = 1**
    For Each rCell In rRange
        If Not IsEmpty(rCell.Value) Then
            rshift = rshift + 1
            **test = 0**
            Exit For
        End If
    Next rCell
    **If test = 1 Then**
        Rows((Row1 - 1 - rshift)).EntireRow.Delete
        Row1 = Row1 - 1
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Thank you for any breadcrumbs of knowledge

Comment: @Matius at which line does it crash?

Comment: @Matius anyway, you defined `Dim test as Boolean` so why not set it up with `test = True` or `test = False` , and later test it with `If test Then`

Comment: Also, `Row1` and `rshift` need to be defined as Long, else you run the risk of encountering an overflow error.

Comment: I have no idea where it crashes, it is just running and running and I have to use ctrl+alt+del to stop whole excel.exe. Using True/False works. But I have no idea why, and I'm seeking some info.

Comment: Why do I need to use Long for "Row1' and 'rshift' ?. It only works with row number within the sheet, I do not see option where it goes anywhere above 1.064 mil. Integer should cover that. Do I not see something?

Comment: @Matus I didn't understand your answer, if you change `test = False` and `test = True` and then checking `If test Then` does your code works ? or it keeps looping and doesn't stop ?

Comment: You are using "Range" and "ActiveCell".  This means the behaviour of your code will depend on which worksheet and cell the user has selected before running it.  Also running it more that once will give different results as the code changes "ActiveCell".  It's generally better to explicitly specify the worksheet and cells you want to work with (e.g. SomeWorksheet.Range, SomeWorksheet.Cells["A3"].

Comment: @Shai Rado, yes, using True/False instead of 1/0 makes the code working in both cases.

Comment: @ Joe this is just a part of bigger code, part that will handle workbooks and worksheets is not in this posting. Also there is a code that firstly maps changes in rows within worksheet, and starts rebuilding them (or skips this part with error report) only after I know where is what. Reference "E508" was just used for this example

Comment: @Matus see my answer below, I modified your code a bit,

Answer (score 0):

Please find code below which is more versatile, and you will be able to adapt quite easily to your needs.
I replaced your first `Do Loop` with `Match` function to fasten the running time, and since it's always better to avoid `Select`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub testcode()

Dim test As Boolean
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRange As Range
Dim Row1 As Long
Dim rshift As Long
Dim efirstRow As Long
Dim elastRow As Long

' set first row on Column E, in this example E508
efirstRow = Range("E508").Row

' set last row on Column E, in this example E2000, modify it to your needs
elastRow = Range("E2000").Row

' find first row match where "test" is found and add the efirstRow reference
Row1 = efirstRow + WorksheetFunction.Match("test", Range(Cells(efirstRow, "E"), Cells(elastRow, "E")), 0) - 1
rshift = 0

Do While Row1 > 626
    Set rRange = Range("A" & (Row1 - 1 - rshift) & ":" & "AD" & (Row1 - 1 - rshift))
    test = True

    For Each rCell In rRange
        If Not IsEmpty(rCell.Value) Then
            rshift = rshift + 1
            test = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next rCell

    If test Then
        Rows((Row1 - 1 - rshift)).EntireRow.Delete
        Row1 = Row1 - 1
    End If
Loop
```